# sql table how to adding array of numbers fetched from sql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In a sql table how to adding array of numbers fetched from sql table

Table like given below

```
   Id         country       Person        Money

   1           UK           john          2010
   2           USA          Henry         120
   3           RUS          neko          130
   4           GER          suka          110
   7           CAN          beater        1450
   8           USA          lusi          2501
```

**This the table How to add a array Money without  USA.**

I want the addition money from table without USA

$Totalmoney=2010+130+110+1450;

sql coding fetching without USA Rows then how to add those money values without USA

```
SELECT Id,country,Person,Money  
FROM Customers   
WHERE country !="USA";
```

Comment: what is your expected output..your question is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(Money)
FROM Customers   
WHERE country !="USA";
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple use the not equal operator `!=`

```
SELECT ID,country,Person,money  
FROM Customers   
WHERE country != "USA";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Money)
FROM Customers   
WHERE country !="USA";
```